# Is there any way to test and debug a website on Amazon Silk without Amazon hardware?

Tags: android, tablet, android-studio, kindle

I want to investigate a bug occurring on a website on a Kindle Fire 10 device running Amazon’s mobile browser called Silk.

Is there any way to do this without a physical Kindle Fire? Internet search isn't returning very many hopeful results.

Comment: Are aware that Silk is based off Chromium?

Comment: Chromium or not, there is a report of a bug that is only affecting certain Fire devices as far as we know. Chrome on Android, even the same base version of Android (9), does not exhibit the bug.

Comment: Amazon is providing their own [Appstore app you can install on Android](https://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/get/amazonapp). I have not checked it but may be Silk browser can be installed using Amazon Appstore on non-Amazon devices?

Comment: You might be able to run Silk with WSA on Windows 11. Have you tried just switching your user agent and setting it to an appropriate screen size?

Comment: [Windows Subsystem for Android](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/android/wsa/) is a fascinating suggestion, thanks. (I’m sure that the issue is not just the user agent string or screen size.)